# Installing packages with R (statistics software) on wine

Tags: windows, r, wine

For various reasons I am forced to use R installed on wine instead the native linux installation I have. The installation works perfectly, but as soon as I try to install additional packages through typing `install.packages("package")` the installation crashes, as R tries to create temporary files on my Linux hard drive! Here comes the error:

```
Error in .install.winbinary(pkgs= pkgs, lib = lib, contriburl = contriburl,  : 
couldn't create temporary directory ‘Z:\tmp\RtmpHIEA7S\downloaded_packages’
```

And `Z:` seems to be equivalent to my root directory. Does anybody know how to change this behaviour in R? For example would it be possible to tell R to only install packages on the C: drive?

Thanks!

Comment: What are the values of the (Windows) environment variables TMP and TEMP?

Comment: There is a `lib` parameter in install.packages.  But you might want to check out `?.libPaths`